# Can I get free PS+ games 'retroactively'?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I just discovered to my utter dismay that I was paying for Plus membership (for over a year), thinking that it is required to access PlayStation Shop. I would have continued to do so, but luckily I saw a YT video, where it was explained that I have free games each month given by Sony.

I was stupid and assume things, which is my fault totally. Now, for the March 2018 I saw BloodBorne given for free, which made me very happy (as I wanted to get that game anyway). 
Also, I checked the previous 'giveawys' and there are some titles I would want to have. Is there a way to get them 'retroactively'?

Comment: Since all your questions have been answered, I just have to add this important info: You can only play these free games when you have an active PlayStation Plus membership. If your membership runs out you can't play these games until you pay again. Sadly.

Comment: On a related note (but not an answer), if you purchase a game for even $0.01 (say, it was discounted 90% to PS+ members), you do get to keep it, even if you later cancel your subscription.

Comment: You don't need this to access the shop, but you do need this if you ever want to play online with others, which is basically the sole purpose and source of joy of the non-story-driven games anyways, e.g. Pro Evolution Soccer. Also I'm pretty sure not allowing the users to play previous free games is exactly the point of their business model.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to retroactively redeem past PS Plus games.

If you haven't redeemed those games when they were free, you'll have to either purchase them or wait until they're offered for free once more.

To redeem a PS Plus game, simply "purchase" it while it is still free. You don't need to actually download the game.

Comment: Oh no :(. Well now I will keep my eyes on it.

Comment: Is there an unofficial way to do it?

Comment: @NuclearWang. I'm not aware of any, sorry.

Comment: it should be noted that after the 8th of March next year (2019) Playstation will stop offering any more PS3 and Vita games (you'll still keep the ones you have now) so after then if you're waiting for an older game to be free again (ie. one of the PS3's Yakuza games) you'll be fresh out of luck

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need to maintain your ps plus subscription to play games you have obtained with PS Plus

Comment: "or wait until they're offered for free once more" – something to keep in mind is that, at least thus far, PS+ free games essentially never repeat. ([full list](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlayStationPlus/wiki/list/fullna))

Comment: @Memor-X didn't they stop offering free games for ps3 already?

Comment: @Jorrit not yet, I believe they will stop March next year

Comment: @Jorrit nope, [here's the web version of the email i got](http://view.playstationmail.net/?qs=171a6481fa72e3b5698f19161fa64411db9533128d2242ec951d2869265d67deecb9f9d74aff15bbb4d216ac779f2527c08546344aa1944b086991a0454c4c7b34651de044ef25e4). if your looking at the though though a console you'll get a filtered view for just that console (ie, viewing the free games on the PS4 will only show you PS4 Games). i generally check [the browser version](https://store.playstation.com/) which will show me all the games regardless of console

Comment: @Memor-X thanks I've had the same mail but couldn't find it anymore. And my memory might have changed the 9 to a 8

Answer (score 6):

You cannot claim free games from past months. For instance, it's April now, meaning if I didn't visit the store and download Bloodborne through PS+ last month then I can't go back and do so now, even if my subscription is still active.

However, if you already claimed a free game in the month it was offered, then wait a few months and remove it from your system, you can go back and re-download it for free as long as you're still subscribed to PS+